# New classification in Machine Learning KNN model

Tags: machine-learning, r, supervised-learning, k-nn

This is my example of KNN model (I write it using R):

```
library(gmodels)
library(caret)
library(class)

db_class <- iris

row_train <- sample(nrow(db_class),nrow(db_class)*0.8)
db_train_x <- db_class[row_train,-ncol(db_class)]
db_train_y <- db_class[row_train,ncol(db_class)]
db_test_x <- db_class[-row_train,-ncol(db_class)]
db_test_y <- db_class[-row_train,ncol(db_class)]

model_knn <- knn(db_train_x,db_test_x,db_train_y,12)

summary(model_knn)

CrossTable(x=db_test_y,y=model_knn,prop.chisq = FALSE)
confusionMatrix(data=factor(model_knn),reference=factor(db_test_y))
```

So, this is a supervised KNN models. How can I classify a new registration?
I have this new registration:

```
new_record <- c(5.3,3.2,2.0,0.2)
```

How can I classify it using the previous model?

Comment: I am not that familiar with `caret` but I think you have to use the `predict` function and pass it a fitted model (so you'd also first have to use `train` to train your model on the data). See also [this example](https://rpubs.com/njvijay/16444).

Comment: ok and how can i do to use it with iris dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use the general `train` from `caret` to train the model
2. The new entry needs to be added in the form of the Train set, only then it will be able to predict

I would have done this like this:

```
library(caret)

model_knn<-train(Species ~ ., data = db_class[row_train,], method = "knn",tuneLength = 10)

#You can select any other tune length too. This is just an example.
#You can even choose to preprocess the data, with the train parameter
```

Now you will have to convert the `new_record` to a suitable data frame:

```
new_record <- c(5.3,3.2,2.0,0.2)

test_data <- NULL

i<-1

while (i <= length(new_record)) {
  test_data <- cbind(new_record[i], test_data)
  i<- i+1
}

colnames(test_data)<-colnames(db_class)[1:4]
```

Now you can make the prediction:

```
predict(model_knn, newdata=test_data)

[1] versicolor
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Prediction using your test data:

```
predict(model_knn, newdata=db_test_x)
 [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     versicolor
 [9] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
[17] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor virginica  versicolor virginica  virginica 
[25] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  versicolor virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Does this solve your purpose?

Comment: No, when I run:
predict(model_knn, newdata=test_data)
I have this error:
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: @Inuraghe have you run the ```model_knn``` that I have run here? It should be a list and not a "factor"

Comment: Sorry, now it works. I tested it with several new records and it always returns the class "versicolor", even if I used values belonging to other classes as a test. Is it a code problem (so it always returns the same class) or is it a model problem (so it has a low accuracy and is not suitable for this problem)?

Comment: I noticed that the new record is inserted in test_data in reverse, so the first value is put in the last column and so on... how can I fix it?

Comment: @Inuraghe are you setting the ```i<-1``` whenever you're running it?

Comment: Also, if possible, can you edit and add 10-20 samples of your test data in the question? @Inuraghe

Comment: Yes, I set ` i<-1`. 
I'm using the iris dataset

Comment: Ok, I fix it with this code:
`new_record <- c(7.7,3.0,6.1,2.3)
test_data <- cbind(new_record)
test_data <- as.data.frame(test_data)
test_data <- t(test_data)
colnames(test_data)<-colnames(db_class[1:ncol(db_class)-1])

predict(model_knn, newdata=test_data, interval='confidence')`

Comment: So it is working now? Also, I tried predicting with your Test data, and it was giving me results: https://imgur.com/sHg0bwz.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129867/discussion-between-shibaprasadb-and-inuraghe).